# pcap_lookupdev function not work in qt

Tags: capture, packet, libpcap

My Code is below :

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *s;
    s=pcap_lookupdev(error_buffer);
    if (s == NULL)
        printf("Could not determine default network device\n");
    else
        printf("%s\n", s);

    return a.exec();
}
```

But it has a Bug:

> (.text.startup+0x3c):-1: error: undefined reference to
>   `pcap_lookupdev'
>
> :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: How are you linking the pcap lib?

Comment: Or, to put it more bluntly, *are* you linking the pcap library? If this is on UN\*X (Linux, \*BSD, OS X, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, etc.), are you linking with -lpcap?  If this is on Windows, are you linking with WinPcap?

Comment: I work in ubuntu 12, I install libpcap-dev and add it in .pro file in qt : QT += pcap, but why give an error? please help me i need to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found, by following the instructions below:

1. Open `terminal`
2. `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev`
3. add `LIBS += -lpcap` to `.pro` file in `Qt`
4. Use of `pcap` `library` is possible without any problem!